# jQueryUI sortable - are complex Selectors possible in 'items'

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got a problem using the sortable function of jQueryUI:

```
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="ui-state-default">
            <h4></h4>
            <input type="text" />
            <button></button>
        </div>
        ...more <div>
    </div>
```

My goal is not to be able to sort the whole div but only the input-element. Is that possible?

I already tried several things, but nothing worked...

```
$(".sortable").sortable({ items: "> input" });
$(".sortable").sortable({ items: "> input[type=text]" });
$(".sortable").sortable({ items: "> div > input" });
$(".sortable").sortable("option", 'items', 'div > input');
```

I already googled for a solution but found nothing except of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918175/can-jquery-uis-sortable-handle-complex-selectors-for-the-items-option), but I don't think the .cancel() function could be a solution for me.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering is that the input box itself can't be made as a draggable handle. You'll need to wrap your input in a span or div and use that instead in the `{ items: }` tag. You still won't be able to pick up the input box itself, so I strongly suggest you use a handle inside the div for dragging to make the operation more intuitive.

Alternatively, you could add a hidden div with `{ position: absolute; width: 100%; height:100% }` on top of the input as a handle but that would make your input uneditable as clicks would hit that div instead of your input.